# Meaning of 'even if' in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Hi could you please describe the meaning of 'even if' in this sentence?

> If we had been able to speak Iranian... can only be used to describe a situation that occurred at some time in the past that had consequences in the past, even if it resulted in further consequences that extend into the present.

Answer (score 1):

"Had been able" is in the **past perfect tense**, which describes things that happened before *another past event*.  Thus:

> *I was detained* at the airport in Tehran, and if **I had been able** to
>   speak Farsi, I wouldn't be in custody today.

So I have mentioned a past event at the airport, and I note something that could have happened before I showed up there, namely learning Farsi.  So my possible ability to learn and be able to speak Farsi is something that I'm talking about in the time before I went to the airport.  So I say "had been able," in the past perfect tense.

It doesn't matter that I probably haven't learned Farsi since I was arrested.  So **even if** my ignorance has effects past its origins, the verb tense remains the same. And it doesn't matter that my detention after I showed up at the airport continues right up to the present.  So **even if** my ignorance then affects my predicament now, the verb tense doesn't change.

When I talk about past events before a past reference point, I use the past perfect.

Comment: The OP is asking what "even if" means.

Comment: @Centaurus OK, another stab in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that you could use that form if there were consequences in the past *and* consequences extending into the present **or** if there were consequences in the past *which did not* extend into the present.

It is making it clear that it is irrelevant whether or not there are also consequences in the present.

Without it, mentioning that there must be consequences in the past *might* be taken to imply "and no consequences extending into the present"; the *even if* clause specifies that there could be consequences extending into the present, but that does not affect the validity of the form.

Answer (score 1):

> If we had been able to speak Iranian... can only be used to describe a situation that occurred at some time in the past that had consequences in the past, even if it resulted in further consequences that extend into the present.

This is a messy sentence.  Rather than trying to give you a technical explanation of "even if it", I am going to try to express the ideas of the sentence with simpler phrasing, so you can use your intuition to understand what's going on.

The construction "If we had been able to speak Iranian", can be used to describe a situation where it would have been helpful to be able to speak Iranian.  For example, "If we had been able to speak Iranian, we would have realized that the driver of the car had never driven a manual transmission before."  Notice that the **benefit** of being able to speak Iranian would also have been **in the past**, for example, "And we would have requested a different driver, and would never have crashed into that bus."  The benefit having been felt *in the past* is an important feature of the construction, even if the benefit continues to be felt in the present -- for example, "and I wouldn't still be stuck in this itchy cast, hobbling around on crutches."

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with 'whether or not'? Your sentence is synonymous to

> If we had been able to speak Iranian... can only be used to describe a situation that occurred at some time in the past that had consequences in the past, **whether** it resulted in further consequences that extend into the present, **or not**.

Another way of putting it might be

> If we had been able to speak Iranian... can **only** be used to describe a situation that occurred at some time in the past that had consequences in the past.

Comment: Or perhaps "regardless of whether"